# Range of Dates that start in 2017 and end in 2018

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, microsoft-flow, timestamp

I am trying to use Flows to get a range of Dates as Integers that start in 2017 and end in 2018

I get my Data from the Get Events (V2) Connector and getting the Start Time and End Time to get the dates.

I am using the range(), sub() and dayOfYear() functions.

My function looks like this:

```
range(dayOfYear(StartDate), sub(dayOfYear(EndDate),dayOfYear(StartDate)))
```

I run into issues when the Start Date is before new year and End Date is after New Year.

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with the financial year running over two years.

I would suggest using your Start Date field as a Date field, so no need to convert it to an Integer.  The calculated fields below work on Date fields and return the data as Text.

Here's the plan:

I used some calculated fields to grab the month and year - using the 'Created Date' as the date source field.  My data is **returned as text** rather the integers, but maybe you can adapt your fields or the formula so it works for you?

**To grab the year data** (Year field)

=""&YEAR(Created)

**To grab the month data** (Month field)

=TEXT(Created,"mm")

**Period** field

=IF(Month<"11",Year,TEXT(Year+1,"0"))

This calculation looks at the Month field.  If the Created date is in Nov 2017 or Dec 2017, the calculation will add +1 to the Period and return 2018.

If you want your Period/Financial Year to run from e.g. April then substitute the 11 for a 4 - in this case your financial year would run from 01/04/2017 - 30/03/2018.  If a Created date was between 01/04/2017-30/03/2018 the Period returned would be 2018.

So in my case (using the Nov to Oct dates) the calculation will see that for a Nov 2017 date a +1 should be added to the year if the month is Nov or Dec.

**List of Field Names**

Created = Created Date field (for your problem, just read 'Created Date' as 'Start Date'

Month = takes the month from the created date and returns it as text

Year = takes the year from the created date and returns it as text

Period = calculation which uses the data from the calculated Month and Year fields and returns data as text