# Retention Policy for Academic Years not Calendar Years

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, date-time, retention

We are wanting to add a retention policy for a site that holds academic material. The retention will be current year plus 5, this is not calendar year. So if a document was created on september 2009 or january 2010 they both would have the date of july 2010 + 5 years for when they should be removed. I could handle this by having a workflow that runs whenever a document is created that calculates the end of year date and then apply the +5years via the retention rule. Is there a better or simpler way of handling this? Specifically calculating the end of year date so I can use a normal retention policy on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post answers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228233/range-of-dates-that-start-in-2017-and-end-in-2018/228292#228292) what you are looking to do.  I had something similar relating to financial years, you have school years vs calendar year, but the solution is the same.

Comment: Thanks I went along this route of using a calculated column.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a content type and use Information Management Policies?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262490.aspx

Comment: Thats what I am looking to do but my question is really relating on how to calculate the end of year date that the retention policy will work off.