# How do I create an formula in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, calculated-column-formula

hope you're well;

I would like to know how to create a formula for weekly in SharePoint online.

For example Tax year is April 2018 but I would like weekly number to be from Tax year.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer on this previously, it should help you - [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228233/range-of-dates-that-start-in-2017-and-end-in-2018/228292#228292).  Although the answer was not accepted :-(